# Mvc views are missing in Azure Package for cloud services

Tags: asp.net-mvc-4, azure

I have azure cloud service with a single web role (Mvc 4). When i run in the local emulator it works as expected but when i package it and deploy in the cloud feedback component was not working and after doing a remote desktop to the machine it was found all the views in the feedback folder was missing.I am using  visual studio 2012 and azure 2.5 SDK.

Every time we give a new build we have manually add the views in the IIS .Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: What's the "feedback folder"?

Comment: All the views related to FeedbackController are in the Feedback folder which is in the views folder. ~views/Feedback.

Comment: So that's `/Views/Feedback` subfolder in the project tree. Does the same happen to views in other subfolders?

Comment: all other subfolder's views are working fine.

Comment: Good! Then you have to find where the difference comes from - how this folder is different. Maybe there's something in the project tree, maybe something else.

Answer (score 0):

Check that the view is included in your .csproj file.

```
<Content Include="Views\Home\yourview.cshtml" />
```

Rather than

```
<None Include="Views\Home\yourview.cshtml" />
```

Comment: Am I missing something? "X" rather than "X"? It's the same string :/